# JSF2 + EJB3 + CRUD with an user control to commit or rollback?

Tags: jpa, jsf-2, transactions, ejb, crud

I'm developping a Java EE application based on JSF2 and Glassfish 3.1. The application has to provide CRUD operations on a database table. The database table data are shown using a primeface dataTable with incell editing behaviour.
I would like to let the user to

- modify, add and remove elements in the table and
- commit only when the user is sure of his changes (pressing a command button)
- rollback when the user wants to discard his changes

The table has an entity and a stateless EJB takes care of interfaces with the entityManager to access the DataBase.

The problem is that everytime I remove a row in the table, the transaction gets committed without any control left to the user.

How can I implement this kind of user control over commits/rollbacks?

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that everytime I remove a row in the table, the transaction gets committed without any control left to the user.

This sounds strange. If you're editing the data in the data table and posting back those edits (via AJAX or direct) AND the data originates from a stateless bean, then it can't be anything other than that you're working on detached entities.

Changes to those entities or the list that contains them, are not automatically reflected in the database. There is no concept of a transaction that gets automatically committed in that  case. I **strongly** disagree with the answer given by Nayan above. Yes, user transactions let you control the commit, but that doesn't seem to be your problem at all.

Although you should maybe show some code, my guess is that you're simply calling a delete method of some sort on your EJB Service after every remove action from the user and then expecting the same transaction and persistence context to be still there. But in a stateless bean those are gone as soon as you exited the method that gave you the entities in the first place.

Your best strategy would be to let the user action operate only on the data that is cached by the `@ViewScoped` backing bean. Then if and only if the user confirms the update action you call your EJB Service with all the changed items in one go. If there is a parent entity that has a reference to a list with among others all those items you deleted, you only have to pass this parent entity and make sure cascade remove is set on the relation.

That said, there IS support for the pattern you seem to think you were already getting. This pattern involves using a `@Stateful` session bean and an `extended persistence context`. In that case the session bean's persistence context will cache all your changes until you associate it with a transaction again. If you do your delete actions in a non-transactional method of the session bean and implement your cancel method also as non-transactional with a `@Remove` and an `entityManager.clear()` and a save method as a transactional @Remove method (doesn't need to do anything in its body) then you'll get this effect.

Unless you have a firm grasp of EJB and transactions you'd best go with the first strategy though.

Comment: I have added more information to the answer, refer edit part & let me know if its not the case.

Comment: @NayanWadekar the text you quote is what happens when an entity gets saved during a transactional method. My point is that OP should not call this transactional method at all until the user confirms.

Comment: Thanks, you are right: when the user click on the remove button, the ejb method remove is called (em.remove(em.merge(entity));). The same for "edit" button (but with em.merge only) and I was erroneously thinking this action should have been committed by the user later, pressing a proper button.

Comment: @ArjanTijms If user is operating on managed entity with CMT, then the changes will be reflected in the database implicitly by container, is there any point to disagree with that.

Comment: @NayanWadekar that by itself is true, but before the user confirms you shouldn't be operating on the managed entity with CMT ;) In other words, operate on the detached entity inside the JSF managed bean. Call the EJB service with its default CMT only after the user confirms. Thus, don't call the ejb's `remove` method after every remove action from the user.

Comment: @ArjanTijms Then I don't understand why you disagreed on transaction committing automatically. Here OP seems to be altering managed entities with CMT & therefore I suggested to clone/detach the managed objects. But if working with managed entities directly, then flushing the changes manually.

Comment: @NayanWadekar As far as I can judge, OP is already detaching the entities (happens automatically). There's simply no way they can stay attached in the given scenario. OP just seems to be calling the Service too soon, so it's not a matter of controlling transactions, but simply a matter of not calling the service again before the user confirms. Working with UserTransaction would therefor not make a difference. The pattern is Service.getData --- detached entities --- let user work on them (many postbacks, no TX involved) --- User confirms --- Service.update (TX starts) --- attach, merge, etc

Answer (score 0):

The user operations are being reflected in the database on frequent basis with activity leading to unnecessary database calls & increasing traffic. Instead you should commit only after the final confirmation from the user.

The changes should be made on the copy of the object or clone & let the user operate on it. When the user wants to save the changes, you can save the modified copy. If changes are to be discarded, then the initial state can be restored from original object.

For your current approach :

> The problem is that everytime I remove a row in the table, the
>   transaction gets committed without any control left to the user.

Its because the default flush mode is `FlushModeType.AUTO`, you can change it to `FlushModeType.COMMIT`.

> How can I implement this kind of user control over commits/rollbacks?

With bean managed transaction using `UserTransaction` interface, you can have control over transaction begin, commit, rollback etc.

---

**Edit :** According to JSR-317, a managed entity *might* get persisted into the database immediately or later afterwards is *implementation specific*.

> If a transaction is active, a compliant implementation of this
>   specification is permitted to write to the database immediately (i.e.,
>   whenever a managed entity is updated, created, and/or removed),
>   however, the configuration of an implementation to require such
>   non-deferred database writes is outside the scope of this
>   specification.